# Breeze error exporting entities from EntityManager

Tags: breeze

when trying to export entities I get the following error:

"Cannot call method 'getProperty' of null"

but ONLY if I had an entity marked for deletion in my manager cache (before calling saveChanges())

this gives me the error:

```
myEntity.entityAspect.setDeleted();
myEntityManager.saveChanges()
   .then(function() {
      var exportedData = myEntityManager.exportEntities();
   })
   .fail(function() {
      //some errorHandling...
   });
```

in contrast, adding or modifying entities before calling saveChanges() and then calling exportEntities() does NOT generate the error!

any help on this, is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug and should be fixed now in v 0.76.2.  Please confirm if this works for you... and thanks for reporting it.

Comment: Thank You a lot! this is great!
realtime support and bug-solving :-)